# T-SQL multiple joins alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Policy` and `Coverage`. `Coverage(policyID)` is a foreign key referencing `Policy(policyID)`. `Coverage` also has columns `covTypeID` and `incurred`. There are multiple coverages per policy. I wrote a query to join these tables with only one row for each policy. This is what I came up with:

```
select polNo, alIncur, apdIncur, cargoIncur
from Policy as P
left join (
  select policyID, incurred as alIncur
  from Coverage
  where covTypeID = 1
) as ALC on ALC.policyID = P.policyID
left join (
  select policyID, incurred as apdIncur
  from Coverage
  where covTypeID = 2
) as APDC on APDC.policyID = P.policyID
left join (
  select policyID, incurred as cargoIncur
  from Coverage
  where covTypeID = 3
) as CARGOC on CARGOC.policyID = P.policyID;
```

I know this query makes three separate passes through the Coverage table and I've heard that `JOIN`s are pretty slow as well. I suspect there's a faster way to accomplish this, and I'm wondering what the best practice would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query without the subqueries, but I don't think that will affect performance:

```
select p.polNo, ALC.alIncur, APDC.apdIncur, CARGOC.cargoIncur
from Policy P left join 
     Coverage ALC
     on ALC.policyID = P.policyID and ALC.covTypeID = 1 left join
     Coverage APDC
     on APDC.policyID = P.policyID and APDC.covTypeID = 2 left join
     Coverage CARGOC
     on CARGOC.policyID = P.policyID and CARGOC.covTypeID = 3;
```

This query will have fine performance if you have an index on `Coverage(PolicyId, covTypeID)`.

One alternative would be to put the different coverages on different rows:

```
select p.polNo, c.covTypeID,
       (case when c.covTypeID = 1 then 'ALC'
             when c.covTypeID = 2 then 'APDC'
             when c.covTypeID = 3 then 'CARGOC'
        end) as which
from Policy P left join 
     Coverage c
     on c.policyID = P.policyID
where c.covTypeID in (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite, it's much more succinct than what I had. So do you think there is no way to improve performance? I know it won't be too slow for my application, but I'd like to know for knowledge's sake.

Comment: Three joins on a table using the right index should be pretty fast.  I wouldn't worry about performance in this case.